# Django in docker. Can't see logs

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to pack a django project into docker environment.

My docker file looks like

```
FROM python:2.7

EXPOSE 8000

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY code /code
WORKDIR /code

ENTRYPOINT ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==1.10.6
```

Everything works fine but id don't see any output from django server.
If I am attaching to container then I can see its output.

But when I am trying to call

> docker logs -f "containerid"

I receive nothing

Comment: If you're only concerned with viewing the output can't you just use `docker logs -f <containerID>` ?

Comment: @JackEvans: when I am trying to call

docker logs -f "containerid"
I receive nothing. (but container works and answers to my requests ) Its my problem.

Comment: Has it been allocated a pseudo-tty? with the -t flag? This should keep stdin open even if not attached

Comment: no i have just started container . via docker run -d . ( actually via docker service ). I also think that is a "terminal issue" - but how can i fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try starting the container with the `-t` flag. In other words add the `-t` flag to the `docker run` command

> -t, --tty     Allocates a pseudo-TTY

Update: `docker service update -t service_name` , note this cmd has to target a manager node.

When you run `docker service create` you can include `-t` flag. The parameters are the same between `create` and `update`.